# RxJS What difference with Scheduler.queue and null?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

[image]

Example:

```
ob$.subscribeOn(Scheduler.queue) 
 .subscribe(() => {...})
```

or

```
ob$.subscribe(() => {...})
```

There is nothing difference, right?

Comment: I've written an article, that explains queue vs null scheduler difference: https://blog.cloudboost.io/so-how-does-rx-js-queuescheduler-actually-work-188c1b46526e

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is apparent when you look at how the `queue` scheduler affects the behaviour of `combineLatest`.

Compare the behaviour of this snippet in which no scheduler (i.e. the `null` scheduler) is specified:

```js
const a = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2);
const b = Rx.Observable.of(3, 4);
const c = Rx.Observable.of(5, 6);

console.log("before");
Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(a, b, c)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
console.log("after");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

With this snippet:

```js
const a = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, Rx.Scheduler.queue);
const b = Rx.Observable.of(3, 4, Rx.Scheduler.queue);
const c = Rx.Observable.of(5, 6, Rx.Scheduler.queue);

console.log("before");
Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(a, b, c, Rx.Scheduler.queue)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));
console.log("after");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Note that both snippets run synchronously. The `queue` scheduler executes scheduled actions synchronously when no delay is specified.

In the first snippet, the observables are enumerated in a depth-first manner. That is, all of the values from the source observable `a` are enumerated before the values from the observables `b` and `c` are enumerated. That sees only two combined values emitted with the last values from `a` and `b` and both values from `c`.

However, in the second snippet the values are enumerated in a breadth-first manner. That is, a value is enumerated from `a` followed by a value from `b`, etc. That sees more combinations emitted.

In short, the `queue` scheduler behaves this way because when an action is scheduled whilst an already-scheduled action is being executed, the newly scheduled action is queued.

Comment: why a,b,c sinks and combineLatest both using Rx.Scheduler.queue ?

Comment: Because if the `of` observables and the `combineLatest` observable don't all use the `queue` schedule, the actions involved in the subscriptions that effect the emitted values won't all be queued. I've not found a compelling use case for the `queue` scheduler. In the past, I've only used it to demonstrate why the `null` scheduler behaves as it does. If you are interested in learning more, I can recommend searching through the issues in the RxJS repo - look for discussions concerning the queue or trampoline scheduler.