# observeOn(queueScheduler) make no difference with null scheduler

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm new to RxJS, and is learning the Schedulers topic, what confuse me is the difference between `queueScheduler` and `null scheduler`.

I have read the RxJS docs and some blogs about this topic.

I thought I've got the idea about the difference, but the following code just break all my 'understandings'.

```js
combineLatest([
  // scheduled([1, 2], asyncScheduler), // [1, 10], [2, 10]
  // scheduled([1, 2], queueScheduler),  // just [2, 10]
  from([1, 2]), // just [2, 10]
  from([10]),
]).subscribe(console.log);
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996986/rxjs-what-difference-with-scheduler-queue-and-null), using the queue scheduler turns the streams somehow 'breadth first', so I was expecting [1, 10], [2, 10] when using the queueScheduler just the same as asyncScheduler in this case.

Any one can explain why this happen, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm not very confident how the `queueScheduler` is implemented and what is its typical real world use-case.

One example where `queueScheduler` and `asyncScheduler` differ is when expecting synchronous behavior while making recursive emissions that trigger another emission. Without any scheduler this would create an infinite loop but with `queueScheduler` I can still have synchronous code.

```
import { observeOn, asyncScheduler, queueScheduler, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject<number>();

console.log('before');
const sub = subject
  .pipe(
    observeOn(asyncScheduler),
    // observeOn(queueScheduler),
  )
  .subscribe(v => {
    console.log(v);
    subject.next(v + 1);

    if (v > 10) {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  });

subject.next(1);
console.log('after');
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-945r4b?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

If you uncomment `observeOn(queueScheduler)` you'll get the same result but the chain is invoked asynchronously.

Regarding using `null` as a scheudler I'm not sure what bahavior is expected. AFAIK a lot has changed since RxJS 5 and how it works with schedulers by default. The answer you mention was posted in 2018 so I would expect that what's written there might be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

**null scheduler**:

Because it runs synchronously, `from([1, 2])` will emit all values almost instantly in the same thread, that's why it looks like "2" is the last value emitted when `from([10])` emits "10".

**queueScheduler**:

While it creates scheduled actions, it also runs synchronously, so it will put 1 and 2 into a queue and then flush it, **behaving just like the `null scheduler`**.

You will see a difference if you also specify the `queueScheduler` to the second `from` (optional) and the `combineLatest`:

```js
combineLatest([
  scheduled([1, 2], queueScheduler),
  from([10]), // If more than 1 value, use: scheduled([10, ...], queueScheduler),
], queueScheduler).subscribe(console.log);
```

Or (non deprecated code),

```js
scheduled([
  scheduled([1, 2], queueScheduler),
  from([10]) // If more than 1 value, use: scheduled([10, ...], queueScheduler),
], queueScheduler).pipe(
  combineLatestAll()
).subscribe(console.log);
```